# angularjs filter two values

Tags: angularjs, filter, ionic-framework

I'm having a problem if it is not easy to solve ta. In my database I have a table in organizations and some of them may be "hidden". You may not see them on a list unless enter a unique code given by the administrator. If the user types the code only then that organization may appear in the list.

My list now looks like this:

```
<a class="item item-avatar" ng-repeat="lugar in organizations_all | filter:search" ng-click="mostrarAreas(lugar.id)" ng-if="organizations_filter !=''" ng-show="!lugar.hide">
  <img image-lazy-src="{{lugar.photo}}" style="border-radius: 0 !important;">
  <button class="button button-icon icon ion-plus-circled" ng-click="agregarLugar(lugar.id,lugar.private);$event.stopPropagation()" style="float: right;"></button>
  <h2>{{lugar.name}}</h2>
  <p class="icon ion-ios-locked" style="font-size:20px;"  ng-show="lugar.private"></p>
</a>
```

Y mi json viene asi :

```
{ "Count" : 5,
"Organization" : [ { "code" : "",
    "hide" : false,
    "id" : "1",
    "name" : "Odebret Advisors Ltda.",
    "private" : false
  },
  { "code" : "",
    "hide" : false,
    "id" : "2",
    "name" : "MOP Ruta 5 Sur (SCL - Talca)",
    "private" : false
  },
  { "code" : "",
    "hide" : false,
    "id" : "3",
    "name" : "MOP Ruta 5 Norte (SCL - Los Vilos)",
    "private" : false
  },
  { "code" : "",
    "hide" : false,
    "id" : "4",
    "name" : "Lixsys SpA",
    "private" : true
  },
  { "code" : "lxspa",
    "hide" : true,
    "id" : "5",
    "name" : "Prueba Oculta",
    "private" : false
  }
],
"status" : 1
}
```

As you can see, there is a "hide" field if true, must hide that organization and also a "code" field is the only code to find and must be entered FULL whereas if we filter by name, you can discriminate by 1 point on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT: This is assuming that the code is contained in your `filter:search` parameter, since you didn't specify where the user is typing the code.**

You'd be better off creating your own filter:

```
.filter('esVisible', function () {
  return function (lugares, search) {
    var lugaresVisibles = [];
    for (var i = 0, ii = lugares.length; i < ii; i++) {
      if (!lugares[i].hide) {
        lugaresVisibles.push(lugares[i]);
      } else if (lugares[i].code == search) {
        lugaresVisibles.push(lugares[i]);
      }
    }
    return lugaresVisibles;
  };
});
```

If you are using another JS utility library as well like [LazyJS](http://danieltao.com/lazy.js/), you could probably simplify the for loop pretty easily.

In the end your ngRepeat would look like this:

```
ng-repeat="lugar in organizations_all | esVisible:search"
```

Note: Untested, but hopefully you get the idea.

Answer (score 2):

just use a && statment in the ng-show so

so for your search input if you have

```
ng-model="searchInput"
```

and in the controller you have

```
$scope.searchInput
```

then on the ng-show you can do

```
ng-show="!lugar.hide && lugar.code == searchInput"
```

Then it will only show them if hide is set to false AND if they have typed in the code. Or if you want to show it even if hide is true, but they typed in the code you can do

```
ng-show ="!lugar.hide || lugar.code == searchInput"
```

Comment: not even work for me, I'm trying to adapt to my problem.

Comment: well I have used this multiple times in multiple apps and it does indeed work. have you used && || comparison and logic operators before?